# Docker compose no crea la carpeta src para laravel

Tags: laravel, windows, docker, src

En docker sobre windows al ingresar al bash del contenedor la carpeta de laravel aunque está físicamente no se visualiza en el bash.

Comment: Por favor, incluye la traza de error completa.

Comment: EN tu pregunta. Edita tu pregunta. EN los comentarios no le podemos dar formato y se pierde :)

Comment: añade el docker-compose o el dockerfile que utiliza para crear el contenedor. Suena a que no tienes un punto de montaje exterior y que no se haya hecho una copia del proyecto en el docker.